# @Where in @JoinColumn relationship does not work

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities "Produto" and "EnderecoProduto" where there is a relationship between them.

In my entity "Produto" I already own a @Where and usually works, but in my relationship "EnderecoProduto", when I list them, is not added to the select clause.

Produto:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SB1010")
@Where(clause = "B1_FILIAL = '' AND D_E_L_E_T_='' AND B1_TIPO='MP'")
public class Produto implements Serializable {
```

NOTE: "B1_FILIAL", "D_E_L_E_T_", "B1_TIPO" are not mapped, but there are in the database.

EnderecoProduto: (not working the @Where)

```
@JoinColumn(name = "pro_cod", nullable = false)
@ManyToOne
@Where(clause = "B1_FILIAL = '' AND D_E_L_E_T_='' AND B1_TIPO='MP'")
private Produto pro_cod;
```

What can I do to make this condition is verified in all relationships that have "Produto" and not only on the entity itself?